# Nginx server won't start on an Ubuntu machine on Digital Ocean

Tags: 18.04, nginx

so i am new to this i am trying to host a website on Digital Ocean the website worked fine before they suspended it due to overdue payment and once that solved i couldn't configure it.

i tried running `service nginx status` and gives me this

[error message from command `service nginx status`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLEu.png)

and when i try to restart the server using this : `systemctl restart nginx`

gives me this error : [error message from command `systemctl restart nginx`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NA8m.png)

what am i doing wrong here?i don't really understand what the error messages mean so any help will be appreciated.

`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'` response :

[`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'` response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzY5a.png)

Comment: Can you post the output of ```journalctl -xe -u nginx```

Comment: i think its very big, how can i copy it all only displays in section?

Comment: i am on the Droplet Console on digital ocean website

Comment: you can always check if your config has issue with `sudo nginx -t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error indicates that port 80 is already bound to.  This usually indicates you have some other webserver running.

Check the output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'` and find what process is using the port.  It's probably Apache, in which case you need to remove the other webserver.

(This is a commonly seen issue on DO droplets and VPSes using prebuilt images)

---

Your output shows that there is an older NGINX process already running.  Run the following commands in sequence:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo killall -9 nginx  # This may say no such process if the previous one worked
sudo service nginx start
```

This should force-kill other NGINX instances and let you fresh-start it with systemd.

Comment: i tried running `sudo killall apache2` earlier and returned `apache2: no process found`

Comment: You need to start by finding out what the process is - which `sudo netstat -tulpn` will indicate what the process is.

Comment: i have edited my question with the result of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'`